# Azure key vault license

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I have a question on Azure licenses.

Does a user require a separate license to connect to Azure Key-vault secrets or the Azure tenant license will be utilized in general? I tried the Azure calculator but wasn't able to figure anything out. Any inputs here would greatly help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Does a user require a separate license to connect to Azure Key-vault
> secrets or the Azure tenant license will be utilized in general?

There is no special license for accessing Azure KeyVault.

A user will be able to connect to an Azure KeyVault and manage keys/secrets/certificates if the user is granted proper permissions (either through Azure RBAC or KeyVault Access Policies) on that KeyVault.

Comment: Appreciate your quick reply. That would greatly help. Do you think there will be a transaction cost? If yes, how is it calculated?

Comment: `Do you think there will be a transaction cost?` - Yes. `If yes, how is it calculated?` -  Please see pricing here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/key-vault/.